# Python: return first value by condition of nested dictionary in array

Tags: python, dictionary

Have some array with nested dictionaries:
`data = [{'id':1, 'name':'test'}, {'id':2, 'name':'test'}, ....., {'id':N, 'name':'test'}]`

Trying to return first `id` value where `name=test`:

`val = [x['id'] for x in data if x['name'] == 'test'][0]`

expected result: `val = 1`

But having exception: `list index out of range`
What's wrong?

Comment: Please show us the full traceback

Comment: It means there's no dict with `name == 'test'` in your list.

Comment: Try next method

Comment: @TerryA, this is a full trace, line and exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works fine for me using your (slightly edited) sample data:

```
data = [{'id': 1, 'name': 'test'}, {'id': 2, 'name': 'test'}, {'id': 3, 'name': 'test'}]
val = [x['id'] for x in data if x['name'] == 'test'][0]

>>> print(val)
1
```

However, if there is no dictionary containing a name that matches the target string:

```
>>> val = [x['id'] for x in data if x['name'] == 'blah'][0]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: list index out of range
```

This is because the list comprehension will create an empty list because there are no dictionaries with `d['name']` set to `'blah'`. Indexing an empty list results in the `IndexError` exception. It's the same as doing this:

```
>>> [][0]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: list index out of range
```

---

A simple way to fix this is to check the list before indexing it:

```
matches = [x['id'] for x in data if x['name'] == 'test']
val = matches[0] if matches else None
```

here it is assumed that `None` can not be used as the value for an `id`.

Another, more efficient way, again assuming that `None` is not a valid `id` is to use [`next()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next) with a default value:

```
val = next((x['id'] for x in data if x['name'] == 'test'), None)
```

This uses a generator expression which avoids generating a whole list containing the matched dictionaries. Instead it will iterate over the `data` list only until the first match is found, or the `data` list is exhausted.

Comment: Alternative fix is to use `next` with generator expression which would also avoid constructing potentially long list: `next((x['id'] for x in data if x['name'] == 'test'), None)`

Comment: @niemmi: Thanks. It looks like I added that to my answer while you were commenting.

Answer (score 0):

```
def getFirstMatchingId(data):
    val = [x['id'] for x in data if x['name'] == 'test'] 
    if len(val) >= 1:
        val = val[0]
        print "Matching ID:-->",val

data = [{'id':1, 'name':'test'}, {'id':2, 'name':'test'}, {'id':3, 'name':'test'}]
getFirstMatchingId(data)

data = [{'id':1, 'name':'test1'}, {'id':2, 'name':'test'}, {'id':3, 'name':'test1'}]
getFirstMatchingId(data)

data = [{'id':1, 'name':'test1'}, {'id':2, 'name':'test1'}, {'id':3, 'name':'test1'}]
getFirstMatchingId(data)

data = []
getFirstMatchingId(data)
```

Above program will give output

Matching ID:--> 1
Matching ID:--> 2